# Hugsql can not read my sql file

Tags: clojure, luminus, hugsql

I am truely lost here. I have a very simple application. All it does is to insert a user into the user table in my Database. I using Postgres. The code is

```
(ns signupper.db (:require [hugsql.core :as hugsql]))
(hugsql/def-db-fns "sql/q.sql")
```

Inside the direvtory where db.clj is I made a directory called sql and inside of it there is a file called q.sql.

When I ran my REPL and type (require '[signupper.db :as db]) I get the following error message:

```
CompilerException clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Can not read file: sql/q.sql {}, compiling:(signupper/db.clj:4:1)
```

Any one has any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: does it work if they are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sql` directory needs to be on the path. Please check your `project.clj` file, under `resource-paths`, and verify your `sql` directory is accessible via one of the paths there stated.

If not, you might either move your `sql` directory or include the path into the `resource-paths` entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) you should add your sql folder under the `:resource-paths` key to your `project.clj` like this:

```
(defproject test-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot test-project.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :resource-paths ["sql" "resources"]  ; <-- here
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hugsql expects the path relative to the directory on the classpath. (This is the same as Clojure namespaces.)

So, your code should look like this:

```
(ns signupper.db (:require [hugsql.core :as hugsql]))

(hugsql/def-db-fns "signupper/db/sql/q.sql")
```

See the example in the docs: https://www.hugsql.org/#start-sql

Comment: I tried it many times, but for some reason that did not work. Defining the resource path in the project.clj did the trick. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

My experience :

If your path is like this :

```
"/home/user/Desktop/sql/q.sql"
```

project.clj must be like this -->

```
:resource-paths ["/home/user/Desktop/sql" "other resources"]
```

and core.clj -->

```
(hugsql/def-db-fns "q.sql")
```

But if you write in core.clj

```
(hugsql/def-db-fns "/home/user/Desktop/sql/q.sql")
```

Computer sees like this :

```
"/home/user/Desktop/sql/home/user/Desktop/sql/q.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue.

Apparently, the function `def-db-fns` starts the path from the folder `src` and not the root of the project.

I think one way you can solve this is putting your file inside the src directory, and call the function with
`(hugsql/def-db-fns "q.sql")`